# What is the purpose of using 'By' in the method arguments?

Tags: java, selenium

In the below method By is used as an argument. Can somebody please explain the use of it.

```
public boolean click(By by, String...elementName) {
    try {
        getElement(by).click();
        if(elementName.length != 0)
            report("PASS", elementName[0] + " is clicked successfully", false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

Answer (score 3):

> By

By is a class in Selenium. It is a mechanism used to locate elements within a document. Various options include

> - ByClassName
> - ByCssSelector
> - ById
> - ByLinkText
> - ByName
> - ByPartialLinkText
> - ByTagName
> - ByXPath

Whatever argument (from one of the above listed) that you will pass to your method will be used to identify the object.

The reason why it (might have been) used as argument is to make the method as dynamic as possible.

Also as shown in comment by @Dinar Zaripov, [this](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) is always good to visit.

Comment: Well explained.